# How to append nuxt element with js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to create a `nuxt-link` from js and put it in a `div`

I am not able to add `nuxt-link` from js. Can someone help me on this.

```
 mounted() {
$(".creator-content .row").append(`
    <nuxt-link to="/">GG</nuxt-link>
`)

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do here exactly? Appending this will not work on the server and could probably be done conditionally with a `v-if`. On top of that, using jQuery for this is also probably redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add references to Vue components by using "vanilla JavaScript" or JQuery operations (unless you use Vue via  tag, which isn't possible via Nuxt).

Instead, this should be part of you Vue component's template. You can then load the component conditionally via directives as [@kissu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585/kissu) described in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71460256/how-to-append-nuxt-element-with-js#comment126306649_71460256).